# How do i write a hash function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

How do i declare a hash function for my custom type so that i could use it in an `unordered_map`?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash for some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<my_custom_type>
    {
        using argument_type = my_custom_type;
        using result_type = size_t;

        size_t operator()(my_custom_type const& x) const
        {
            // Perform your hash algorithm here.
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I get the error (using g++): error: passing 'const std::hash<superposition>' as 'this' argument of 'std::size_t std::hash<superposition>::operator()(const superposition&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive].

Comment: You need a `const` qualifier in the function. Also, i don’t know what is the purpose of the `using` statements — the program works fine without them.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Function adapters and the like need those type definitions. You could leave them out if you only want to use this directly for hashing, and not do any fancy functional stuff with it; but they don't do any harm and might be useful one day.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to provide a specialization of std::hash< class Key > with std::hash< mytype >.